# ARMA(p,q) estimation

Tags: estimation, arima, least-squares

In some statistical notes, it is written that it is possible to estimate ARMA(p,q) from the two-step regression, i.e. first is to fit AR and estimate the errors and then to use these errors in the second step OLS to estimate ARMA (p,q).

In other econometric textbooks, it is written that fitting AR regression if the true DGP is ARMA gives inconsistent estimates since the regressors are correlated with errors in this case.

So my question is what is the correct procedure of estimating ARMA (p,q) and whether two-step OLS can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Your first step AR regression needs to have a high order. Then it approximates the ARMA DGP. The errors from that regression can then be used in the second step ARMA estimation using OLS. This is part of the Hannan-Rissanen algorithm (https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/69.1.81). The other part of the HR algorithm is to select $p$ and $q$ based on a BIC approximation.